# Java: Netbeans debugging session works faster than normal run

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I'm making a clone of the game [Braid](http://www.braid-game.com) in Java with Netbeans 6.7.1 for fun and learning purposes.

Computer Spec:

```
Windows 7
Running processes: 46
Running threads: +/- 650
NVidia GeForce 9200M GS
Intel Core 2 Duo CPU P8400 @ 2.26Ghz
```

Game-spec with normal run:

```
Memory: between 80 MB and 110 MB
CPU: between 9% and 20%
CPU when time rewinding: 90%
```

The same values for the debugging session, **except when I rewind the time: CPU: 20%.**

Is there any reason for? Is there a way to reach the same performance with a normal run.

This is my repaint code:

```
 @Override
 public void repaint()
 {
     BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy(); // numBuffers: 4
     Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     g.fillRect(-1, -1, 2000, 2000);
     gamePanel.paint(g.create(x, y, gameDim.width, gameDim.height));
     bs.show();
     g.dispose();
     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
     update(g);
 }
```

The game runs in fullscreen (undecorated + frame.size = screensize)

Martijn

Comment: Braid is written in Java?
neat :), wouldn't have guessed.

Comment: @OmryYadan: No it's not. I was writing a clone back then to learn some game development.

Comment: blast from the past, replying to a comment from 2009 :)

Answer (score 2):

Which framework do you use? Or did you write one yourself? In the latter case, are you using System.currentTimeMillis() or System.nanoTime() to limit the FPS?

Debugmode may change the resolution of the OS interrupt rate under Windows and therefore changing the resolution of System.currentTimeMillis() too.

I had a similiar case in which my game did run faster when using VisualVM. Using System.nanoTime() instead of System.currentTimeMillis() to calculate the value for Thread.sleep() fixed it.

You can read more on this topic here:
http://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks

Comment: this is intresting, thanks. But I add some info about the cpu.
I use two threads: 1 updater, 1 repainter

Comment: Now, when I make games in Java, I always use your Bonsai Lib. I like very much.

Answer (score 1):

The `repaint()` method is cheap because multiple requests are coalesced before being processed. I'll take a guess that under the debugger more repaints are being coalesced into actual calls to `paint()`.

Try keeping a counter that is updated on each call to `paint()` or `paintComponent()`. If I'm right, you should see less calls when running under the debugger.